# Linking bootstrap button to url in Flask using send

Tags: flask

My code goes this way

```
@app.route("/mcap_format/<mcformat>")
def mcap_format(mcformat):
    return send_from_directory(app.config["mcap_format_loc"],filename=mcformat,as_attachment=False)
```

This works fine , when I open. /mcap_format/mcformat , the document gets downloaded. however when I link this to a button it fails.

html code here

```
<div class = "col-md-3">
<button type="button" id = "cmap_download" onclick = "window.location.href= '{{ url_for('/mcap_format',filename = 'mc1.xlsx')}}';" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >Downlaod the format<!/button>
 </div>
```

Any reason it is not working ?

Comment: First you are not using the same function, so you may not have the same behavior,

Comment: Thanks for the input , have made mistake there